# sqlite to coredata

Tags: sqlite, core-data

Can we map an sqlite file to coredata?

Answer (score 1):

You can use sqlite as the persistent store for Core Data. Yes. This happens by default using the Xcode templates.

You can load data from sqlite into Core Data. Yes. Open your sqlite db, and load the records into Core Data.

There are several Core Data tutorials located on the Web.

If you're asking can you map an existing sqlite db into Core Data. Theoretically, however, loading data from an existing sqlite db into Core Data using the core data methods is far easier.

Answer (score 1):

From Core Data Programming Guide [FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFAQ.html):

> **How do I use my existing SQLite database with Core Data?**
>
> You don’t. Although Core Data supports SQLite as one of its persistent store types, the database format is private. You cannot create a SQLite database using native SQLite API and use it directly with Core Data (nor should you manipulate an existing Core Data SQLite store using native SQLite API).If you have an existing SQLite database, you need to import it into a Core Data store (see “[Efficiently Importing Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html)”).

In most cases what you do is to import data from your database to a Core Data store in a separate application and then you use the resulting file in the real application. This way you avoid the unnecessary overhead of importing the data in your app.

For the actual import, you can use *find-or-create* pattern, it may not be the most efficient method, but it won't be a problem if you import the data offline (outside your real application).